# Android EditText inserting

Tags: android, android-edittext

How do I insert characters into the middle of an EditText field?
I'm making a calculator that can take a string expression like "3*(10^2-8)".   I'm using an EditText field to make the string using XML like so:

EditText

```
android:id="@+id/entry"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/label"
android:text="@string/testString1"
android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
```

and then in my activity I have, say:

```
entry = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.entry);
entry.setText("blablahblah");
entry.setSelection(3);
```

Now I have an EditText field with the cursor blinking after the third character in the string. How do I insert a character there, so it correctly says "blahblahblah"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method getText() of the EditText widget returns an object that implements the Editable interface. On this object you can call the [insert()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html#insert%28int,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method to insert text at a certain position.

I found this out by reading the documentation, but never used this myself. But for your needs, to insert a character at the selected position in the EditText, the following should work:

```
Editable text = entry.getText();
text.insert(entry.getSelectionStart(), "h");
```

Comment: Thanks Jan-Henk.  I didn't understand that it implements the Editbale interface so I didn't check there.  Here's what I'm using.   This way I can just use whatever insertion point is selected already.
        Editable entryE1 = entry.getText();
        entryE1.insert(entry.getSelectionStart(), "1");
It seems to work great.

Comment: I updated my answer with the getSelectionStart() method you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a String called str and it contains "blablahblah" and you want to make it "blahblahblah" you can do the following:

```
String newString = str.substring(0, 3) + "h" + str.substring(3);
```

Take the first 3, add the new letter, place everything else. So you could take the String from the EditText, change it like this and then put the new String as the new value of the EditText.